# Innacurate Higher/Lower

Tags: python

I used a code snippet that I found online of a higher/lower traditional card game, I wanted to use this for an enemy system. Half of the time it isn't very accurate though. Sometimes it says higher instead of lower and vice-versa. I tried to remake it in my own way, but it had the same issues. I'm not sure how else to fix it, any suggestions are appreciated. Correct, incorrect and draw are all similar things, that's why only correct is included in the snippet.

Edit: I've gotten my code to this point, but not sure how to connect the values to the ranks

```
ranks, values = [["Ace ","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack ","Queen ","King "], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
suits = ['♠', '♦', '♥', '♣']
deck = []
        
for rank in ranks:
    for suit in suits:
        deck.append([rank + suit])
    
random.shuffle(deck)
enemy = deck.pop(0)
second = deck.pop(0)
```

Comment: You'll have to define how the cards compare; Python hasn't defined the card ranks (in fact, it knows nothing about them). As far as Python is aware, you're comparing two strings. Since the K (from King) is later in the alphabet than the "J" (from Jack), a Jack will likely be considered higher value than a King. And that's ignoring the four card suit symbols, for which the order is unknown to me.

Comment: There are examples out there (that is, on the internet), that define a set of cards (using e.g. Python enums), with proper comparisons (or such that you can set which suit tops which other suit, if any). I suggest it's time for some internet browsing and research.

Comment: Note that you're getting some downvotes, likely because you have lots of code that has nothing to do with the actual problem (but just with input/output and presentation); trim down your problem to the actual problematic code, possibly even try and ignore user input. Just create code with some fixed card comparisons where you expect one result, and you get another. *Then* you can start debugging yourself (or search for alternative implementations as suggested above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 2d array, one array that holds the strings for drawing to the screen, and one array paralelled to it with values 1-13 representing the actual value of the card for comparison.  Then when you see a Rank[7] vs Rank[king] your value array will simple compare int[7] (which is the 8th value in the array) with int[12] (which is the 13th value in the array) and come back with a correct answer.